# HTML <select> has locked CSS applied, and I want it to display as browser defaults

Tags: html, css, select, overriding, default

I can't edit the CSS file, which has the following values:

```
font-size: 13px;
padding: 6px 4px;
background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);
clear: both;
margin-bottom: 4px;
```

I know I can use the `!important` tag, but when I try to override with the default values, it still doesn't display the same was a CSS-less (clean) `<select>` drop-down would.

Thanks

Comment: can one use javascript or some framework?

Comment: Have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GreatBigBore/W5JHm/2/). I started with a `<select>` and used Chrome's 'inspect element' to get all of the style info, including the computed styles. It seems to work. I'm sure it could be stripped down considerably.

Comment: What exactly did you try?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set a property of an element to browser default, once there is *any* CSS rule in effect that assigns a value to the property of the element. For example, if any style sheet sets `font-size: 13px` on a `select` element, there is no way to tell a browser to behave as if that setting just didn’t exist and use its default instead.

What you can do is to set a property to an explicit value, e.g. `select { font-size: 18px }`, and this will override other settings by normal cascade rules. If this did not work for you, then there is some problem in the specific way you used.

You might try to set properties to explicit values that you believe to be browser defaults, but there is no guarantee that all browsers, current and future, will have those values as their defaults.

In an earlier draft for CSS Cascading and Inheritance Level 3, there was a proposed `default` keyword that would “roll back the cascade”. But it has been dropped in the [current version](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-css3-cascade-20130103/#default) of the draft, which proposes the `unset` keyword instead, but its definition does not mean using browser defaults (but initial values as per CSS specifications).